# File "not declared in scope" even though it was

Tags: c++, file, scope

Part of my program includes writing to a text file. I have:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

//I open the file "highscore.txt" here, read it, and then close it.

ofstream outfile;

outfile.open("highscore.txt", ios::out);

outfile<<score;

outfile.close();
```

I asked different people and it said it looks right, but when I try to compile it am getting the error:

> "outfile" was not declared in this scope

Comment: I only see global scope. What are you trying to do? Do you have an MCVE?

Comment: Where is your `main()` function?

Comment: Where is your main function?  You cannot run code in the global scope

Comment: This is not a complete example, please provide a more meaningful one.

Comment: `main` functions are so overrated these days.  This program identifies as a main-free program.

Comment: @skypjack I suspect the OP's problem is that this *is* his complete example :)

Comment: Ha ha, @LukePark, don't confuse the guy! :D

Comment: @LukePark and other people of course I had the main and the variables initialized, I just didn't include them here because it's a small part of my program and I can't copy and paste from linux to windows so I only wrote the things which I toguht might cause problems

Comment: Wild guess: the variable is declared in one function and used in another. Or, there's a typo in you real code that disappeared when you retyped it.

Comment: The Magic 8 Ball says "Outlook good." Clearly it has never had to use Outlook. Trying again I get, "Better not tell you now." This isn't working. I think we need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT:** Since according to the OP, the code *is* in a function, and `score` is defined, this is more than likely a case of the computer
>   being a jerk. Restart should theoretically solve the problem.

The code's logic is correct as it stands. Syntactically, there are two major problems: it **must be in a function**, and `score` has to be defined, (though that's unrelated to this error).

I'm going to take a guess that you're coming from a language like Python, where you can run code straight. As Nathan Oliver and Fabio Turati pointed out, you appear to lack an `int main()` function, which is required for all C and C++ programs.

Check out the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) for ofstream to see a working version of your code.

Comment: Well, that and `score` isn't defined.

Comment: Yes, that too. Missed that. >.>

Comment: It is not correct at all, unless a variable named `score` uses to appear magically in the code... :-)

Comment: @skypjack This was just a small part of my program. I had score defined, and of course I had the main function above

Comment: I only included the things which I tought might be causing the errors

Comment: But, as it stands, it wasn't in a function?

Comment: @skypjack, as I mentioned, I had missed that. Edited to include it.

Comment: @Ovi: You need to post an example that actually shows the error you got when compiled. I put your code in a `main()` and added `score` and it compiled and worked. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JasonMc92 yes it was in a function. I am just going to restart my machine and see if it helps

Comment: Good idea, because aside from the aforementioned your code is virtually identical to the documentation.

Comment: @JasonMc92 well, still almost totally correct? ;-)

Comment: @skypjack, when it comes to defining and using an ofstream, yes, almost totally correct. While effectively significant, the two errors (which apparently are NOT the problem according to OP) are so simple and elementary. It isn't like he used a funky constructor or passed a pointer to his childhood home or something. In other words, the *logic* is spot on.

Comment: @skypjack, That said, I'll reword that phrase if you think it's important, all the same. I'm not overly attached to anything I write. *Shrug*

Comment: Just kidding, it doesn't really matter that sentence!! Sorry for the misunderstanding, I don't want to bother you absolutely.

Comment: @skypjack, not a problem. Wording is important, so I appreciate feedback. (I also associated your comment with a downvote I received at the same time, so I assumed you were serious.) :)

Comment: @JasonMc92 got back ;-)